# Glossaries-extra: how to always expand the first plural use of an acronym?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra, plural

The question is regarding the **first plural usage** of acronyms. Consider the following `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}

\begin{document}

In this work, a new model of \gls{adc} has been designed. blah blah ....

% lots of text here and finally we reach conclusion section where the 
% following sentences appear

This design exercise was motivated by the fact that the current crop of 
\glspl{adc} fail to bring aliens down to earth..... blah blah...

Results indicate that compared to the existing bunch of \glspl{adc}, 
this design is the best thing since slided bread. While other \glspl{adc} 
were sub-optimal in blah blah ....

\end{document}
```

When this `MWE` is run with `pdflatex`, it will expand the first use of the acronym. In all subsequent uses, the plural form of the acronym will be typeset, but without expansion as expected.

Now, my PhD advisor has an unusual request. They would like the **first plural usage** of acronyms to be treated the same as the first usage of that acronym, i.e. need to *expand* them.

How can one achieve this using `glossaries-extra`?